# Magnetic switch, master/slave socket and dust collection

Tags: switches, wiring

I have a dust collection (JET DC-1100CK) and table saw. I bought a [400V master/slave unit](https://www.peddy.cz/prislusenstvi-k-bruskam-na-drevo/kompaktni-rozvodna-skrin-holzmann-ala-1), connected all together and it does not work.

I talked to the JET seller and he told me that the dust collection uses a magnetic switch and is only compatible with the master/slave unit made by JET.

I don't want to resort to rewiring the switch, due to warranty, yet. Do you have some ideas how to fix this without breaching warranty (ie. by not messing the dust collection at all)?

One stupid idea I had was to use a strong magnet to hold it in ON position all the time, but it's probably stupid and naive, or?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to clamp the ON button, so it's always pressed. Not elegant, but does the job and does not breach warranty.